# Accessing user created variables for an array in a separate class Java (for homework)

Tags: java, arrays, reference, subclass, user-input

I am super new to Java (4 days) and have never really coded anything except SQL databases and some simple java script before. I am building a sales commission calculator with a special policy that adjusts the amount of commission made based on an annual sales amount tier system (<=96,000, >96,000<=120,000 and >120,000).

I have that completed. . .What I need now is a way to use a second class(a second class is required ) to create an array that takes the output or input to/from the user and shows the user the potential money he/she could have made if his or her sales were at "X" in increments of 5,000 up to 50% of the user input for total sales. Here is the code I have so far: (I know my SystemOutTest class was in bad form sorry)

```
/**
 *
 * @author Wudkong
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SystemOutTest {
    Potentialwagechart Potentialwagechart;

    public SystemOutTest(Potentialwagechart Potentialwagechart) {
        this.Potentialwagechart = Potentialwagechart;

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // main method for mathematics
        Scanner input; // determines the method for the scanner
        input = new Scanner(System.in); // creates an instance of scanner
        int salary; // creates variables to be used later
        int totalSales;
        double commissionPercent;
        double totalPay;
        double commission;

        salary = 50000; // defines a variable to a specific value for annual
                        // salary

        System.out.print("enter annual sales amount please: ");
        /**
         * asks the user for the amount sold for the year
         */

        totalSales = input.nextInt();
        /**
         * creates dialogue box for user to enter the annual sales amount
         */

        commissionPercent = .15; // defines received total from sales data
        if (totalSales <= 120000 * .8) {
            commissionPercent = 0;
        } else if (totalSales > 120000) {
            commissionPercent = .1875;
            ;
        } else
            commissionPercent = .15;
        {
            commission = totalSales * commissionPercent;
            /**
             * Uses user defined data and commission percentage to create a
             * value for total commission amount
             */
            totalPay = commission + salary; // adds totals together
            System.out.printf("Total annual pay is %.2f ", totalPay);
            /**
             * this uses an output stream to report to the user of the result of
             * the method with just two decimal places showing.
             */
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to start the next class here but I am willing to take advice on just about anything. I know my code is sloppy and I do not know the best way to do this next part. I think I can build an array from a constant object just not an object that needs to be acquired from the user first. I also do not know how to make my classes communicate in the best way. I tried creating a reference to my second class in my first class and vice-versa but without the array or the object reference in place I can't test those links. Any help here is appreciated! I don't know if a get/set method can work or if I need to reference the output instead of the user input to create the array output plus 5,000 and the new potential  wage on the side for x spaces. . ?

Comment: I have quite a few questions in there but most can be answered by answering one: How do I use the user input to create an array from a second class? Using Netbeans 8.0.2

Comment: @Vogel612 thx, that gave me a better understanding. I removed my comment.